# grep surrounding lines in SunOS 5.9

Tags: bash, grep, sunos

Trying to grep surrounding lines using SunOS 5.9, normally I would use grep with -B and -A to do so:

```
grep -B 3 -A 2 foo README.txt
```

However, in SunOS 5.9, grep don't support this feature with this error message:

```
grep: illegal option -- A
```

below is what I get from "man grep":http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS+5.9&format=html

My example would be try to grep with keyword "Mirror" and those lines representing the state of its Submirror. Inputs to grep would be:

```
d6: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d61
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d62
      State: Okay
    Pass: 1
    Read option: ***
    Write option: ***
    Size: ***

d61: Submirror of d6
    State: Okay
    Size: ***
    Stripe 0:
    Device     Start Block  Dbase        State Reloc Hot Spare
    CCC          0     No            Okay   Yes


d62: Submirror of d6
    State: Okay
    Size: ***
    Stripe 0:
    Device     Start Block  Dbase        State Reloc Hot Spare
    BBB          0     No            Okay   Yes
```

In the above case, I want to get

```
d6: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d61
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d62
      State: Okay
```

How should I do so in SunOS 5.9?

Comment: This question is probably better off at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/Mirror/,/Pass:/{/Pass:/d;p;}' file
```

Output:

```
d6: Mirror
    Submirror 0: d61
      State: Okay
    Submirror 1: d62
      State: Okay
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it looks like you only want to print lines *after* the match. If that's the case, then you can use this awk script:

```
awk '/Mirror/ { c = 5 } c && c--' file
```

It sets `c` to 5 when the pattern matches and prints lines as long as `c` is greater than 0 (so the next 4 lines).